# In a logit model, what test does the p-value refer to in the Stata margins command when it reports the marginal standardized probability values?

Tags: p-value, stata

I understand the output of the margins command gives the weighted average predicted probability at each value of a factor (averaged over the other confounders), but I am not clear what the p-value is referring to, that is, what is the null hypothesis being tested? If it reports 0.06 and 0.09 respectively for a two level factor with a significant p-value for both levels, what does that actually mean? How do these p-values relate to the p-values for the factor coefficients in the actual model?

This paper describes what the method used by the margins: http://ije.oxfordjournals.org/content/43/3/962.full

Specifically, the section that begins "To apply method 1 in practice after performing a logistic regression..."

I don't have specific example output, but an example output of this command is on page 12 here: 
http://www.stata.com/manuals13/rmargins.pdf

Comment: could you include some output from the margins command?  Please use the code tag around your output so it's formatted correctly

Comment: And please include a link that explains exactly what Stata is doing here.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I've added a few links. Another description of this method can be found in Gelman and Hill, section 5.6, but p-values are not explored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not provide any code, so it's hard to tell what `margins` is doing, since it can do a great number of things. It is good practice to provide code, or--even better--a replicable example. Stata makes this very easy.

My best guess from reading your description is that your `margins` is conducting a test that the average predicted probability (with own covariates and setting the factor variable to each value sequentially) is *individually* zero. This is usually not very meaningful. These predictions use the index coefficients that `logit` spits out, multiplied by the covariates and wrapped up inside a `logistic()` function.

Here's an example where the outcome is giving birth to low birthweight child and we will predict that as if all mothers are white, then black, and then other, holding age at own values. Then we will repeat what `margins` does by hand using a loop for each race:

```
. webuse lbw, clear
(Hosmer & Lemeshow data)

. qui logit low age i.race

. margins race, post

Predictive margins                              Number of obs     =        189
Model VCE    : OIM

Expression   : Pr(low), predict()

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |     Margin   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
        race |
      white  |   .2469149   .0446876     5.53   0.000     .1593288    .3345011
      black  |   .4069807   .0961398     4.23   0.000     .2185502    .5954113
      other  |   .3657971   .0585134     6.25   0.000      .251113    .4804812
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. 
. /* Replicate each row of margins */
. forvalues v=1/3 {
  2.         local race: label race `v'
  3.         di _newline(1) "`race'"
  4.         di "z-stat: "    %9.2f (_b[`v'.race]-0)/_se[`v'.race]
  5.         di "p-value: "   %9.2f normal(-(_b[`v'.race]-0)/_se[`v'.race])
  6.         di "95%CI LB: "  %9.7f _b[`v'.race]-abs(invnormal(0.025))*_se[`v'.race]
  7.         di "95%CI UB: "  %9.7f _b[`v'.race]+abs(invnormal(0.025))*_se[`v'.race]
  8. }

white
z-stat:      5.53
p-value:      0.00
95%CI LB: 0.1593288
95%CI UB: 0.3345011

black
z-stat:      4.23
p-value:      0.00
95%CI LB: 0.2185502
95%CI UB: 0.5954113

other
z-stat:      6.25
p-value:      0.00
95%CI LB: 0.2511130
95%CI UB: 0.4804812
```

Also, here's what `margins` is doing under the hood to get the white prediction of .2469149:

```
qui logit low age i.race
replace race = 1
predict phat, pr
sum phat
```

Comment: Got it, that makes sense- as you point out, the test of whether each marginal average predicted probability is 0 doesn't seem likely to be interesting within the context of a model with covariates. I wonder why it would be shown by default.

Comment: @jeffmax329 My guess is that most people look at marginal effects or index coefficients, in which case the null of zero is a more or less meaningful, and margins inherits this default behavior. It is also easy enough to suppress the p-values. You can also look at contrasts of these margins or do tests on them after `post`ing, which will accomplish the same goal.

Comment: Another area where this bites is when you ask for exponentiated logit coefficients with the `or` option, in which case the baseline is 1 rather than 0, since the effect is multiplicative on the odds-ratio scale. Stata gives you the p-value for the null that $\exp(\beta)=0$, which is strange.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov Can you please explain why you calculate the z-score of the margins the same way you would calculate the z-score of the coefficients? I've written [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/339214/is-the-t-value-or-z-value-of-the-margins-of-a-logit-model-equal-to-the-t-value) about it, thanks!